# ENV how to implement

Tags: spring-batch

I created a simple SpringBatch - SpringBoot application. Currently I have one datasource configured in my resources->application.properties.

I would like to be able to move this to a higher env and try some runs, but the URL/username/password is different in our next env than my local.

It is easy to change my file, but I keep seeing people talk about ENV. Not finding assistance in Spring Batch reference doc. Can someone guide to me a link or help me understand how this would work? I would assume the system is runs on must know its ENV and then somehow the code reads that and uses the right property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your configuration is being done by spring boot, then you can externalize it. So in addition to using app.properties or yaml files, values can be passed to your application via command line parameters, jvm properties, JNDI values, and system environment variables.

It's very well thought out and quite well documented here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

This feature makes it easier to deploy your application to different environments without having to change your core application artifacts.